# PHP MySQL DB query error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the top 10 items from a table:

```
<?php
  include DBConnect.php;
  $dbname = 'Telejoke';
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM jokes LIMIT 10";
  $data = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
  mysql_close($conn);
  $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
?>
```

The PHP script keeps executing the die part saying that my query insert failed.

UPDATE:

The error is `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

UPDATE 2:

I think the user I connect to DB is not authorized to use the SELECT command. This would cause the preceding error?

Comment: What's in "DBConnect.php"? Are you sure you're connecting to your database entirely. Try something like this: $data = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed: ' . mysql_error()); Should give a more detailed error message so you know where to begin.

Comment: now depends whats in your `DBConnect.php` and also whether there is really a `table` like `joke` inside a DB `TeleJoke`

Comment: Use `mysql_error` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to check the error message.

Comment: Error should be in DBConnect.php file post the contents of that file.

Comment: could it be that I use DBConnect.php in another PHP file to connect to the DB? I use DBConnect.php in another script, TeleJokeUpload.php and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In db connection.php you must use a user name with password who is allowed to do operations on db.